# Getting specific values from many-to-many relationships

Tags: mysql

My database looks like this, I have client accounts which are assigned to specific profiles, and I have profiles which are assigned to specific categories, like in this schema:

```
| categories  |    | profiles  |    | categories_map           |
---------------    -------------    ----------------------------
| ID | name   |    | ID | name |    | ID | profile_id | cat_id |
---------------    -------------    ----------------------------
| 1  | cat1   |    | 1  | p1   |    | 1  |   1        |   1    |
| 2  | cat2   |    | 2  | p2   |    | 2  |   2        |   1    |
| 3  | cat3   |    | 3  | p3   |    | 3  |   3        |   1    |
                   | 4  | p4   |    | 4  |   1        |   2    |
                                    | 5  |   3        |   2    |
                                    | 6  |   4        |   3    |


| profiles_map              |
-----------------------------
| ID | profile_id | acc_id  |
-----------------------------
| 1  |  1         |  1      |
| 2  |  3         |  1      |
| 3  |  4         |  1      |
```

I need to get categories assigned to accounts - which means when I want to get categories for acc_id = 1, I should get categories with ID 2 and 3 ( category with ID 2 doesn't fit because it contains profile with ID 2 which isn't assigned to this account). I tried this query but it doesn't work

```
select cats.id from profiles_map map 
right join categories_map catm on catm.profile_id = map.profile_id 
right join categories cats on cats.id = catm.cat_id 
where catm.profile_id in (select profile_id from profiles_map where acc_id = 1) 
and map.acc_id = 1 group by cats.id;
```

Could anybody help me with this question?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.ID
    FROM profiles_map PM
    INNER JOIN categories_map CM ON CM.profile_id = PM.profile_id
    INNER JOIN categories C ON C.ID = CM.cat_id
    WHERE PM.acc_id= 1
```

Comment: Still finding categories with profiles which aren't assigned to this account

Comment: There must be something wrong with your schema, or the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only category id, Please try following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cm.cat_id FROM categories_map cm 
    WHERE cm.profile_id in 
    (SELECT profile_id FROM profiles_map WHERE acc_id = 1)
```

Or if want to get category name and id then , use following query:

```
SELECT cat.id,cat.name FROM categories cm 
    WHERE cat.id in (SELECT DISTINCT cm.cat_id FROM categories_map cm 
    WHERE cm.profile_id in 
    (SELECT pm.profile_id FROM profiles_map pm WHERE pm.acc_id = 1))
```